# LaTeX Error: File `memsty.sty' not found

Tags: memoir

I am trying to compile memman.tex:

```
% Memoir class user manual (Part II only)  last updated 2009/09/07
% Author: Peter Wilson
% Copyright 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2008, 2009 Peter R. wilson
```

I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `memsty.sty' not found.
```

How do I add the package to my MacTex install? I have OS X 10.8.4 and TeXLive-2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memsty.sty` file is in the same folder as `memman.tex` in your TeX distribution, that is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir
```

You can navigate to this folder by hitting Command-Shift-G in a Finder window and typing `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex` in the box. Find the `memoir` folder and copy it in your home. Then open the `memman.tex` file inside the copied folder and compile it (for instance with TeXShop).

The `memsty.sty` file is a “private” package, so it's not in the standard directories for packages.

Comment: It is only ment to be used to build the memoir manual, thus not in the normal three

Comment: For the benefit of other users looking for the same answer, my home file is: "~/usr/texbin"